# How can I search & replace numbers with numbers+1000

Tags: python, regex, json

I'm working with a JSON file that has values for rows and columns, and I need to create a unique id based on those values.  We decided to combine the values row and column, and make sure each is represented by four digits (add 1000 to each).

For example:

`"Col_Row": "1 - 145"` needs to be something like `"Geo_ID": "10011145"`

I thought maybe I could do this with Python and regex, because I have to search for `"Col_Row"`.

Here's what I have:

```
output = re.sub(r'"Col_Row: "(.*?)",', r'\1', test);
output = output.split(' - ')
[1000+int(v) for v in output]
```

So I can get the values, but now I'm stumped on how to search/replace a very large JSON file with those values.

Comment: Python has a `json` module, why don't you use it?

Comment: @fge I've been looking at it, but can't figure out how to manipulate values with it.

Comment: Be serious..manipulationg a json string directly is broken

Comment: It maps JSON to native Python structures -- a dict for a JSON object for instance. Therefore a JSON object can be manipulated just like a dict.

Comment: I'm actually thinking that a regex callback is simpler: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094975/python-re-sub-question#answer-2095012

Comment: Not sure why I'm getting downvoted...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found how to do calculations to regex references through a callback function, as displayed in this question: [Python re.sub question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094975/python-re-sub-question#answer-2095012)

So here's the python that worked for me:

Example:

```
import re
test = '"Properties" : { "Col_Row": "1 - 145", ... "Col_Row": "130 - 240" ... }}'
def repl(m):
  num = "%d%d" % (int(m.group(1))+1000,int(m.group(2))+1000)
  string = '"Geo_ID": "%s", "Col_Row": "%s - %s",' % (num,m.group(1),m.group(2))
  return string
output = re.sub(r'"Col_Row": "(.*?) - (.*?)",', repl, test)
```

outputs: `'"Properties" : { "Geo_ID": "10011145", "Col_Row": "1 - 145", ... "Geo_ID": "11301240", "Col_Row": "130 - 240" ... }}'`

And now the real thing (manipulating a file):

```
input = open('fishnet.json','r')
input_list = input.readlines()
output = open('updated.json','w')
for line in input_list:
  updated = re.sub(r'"Col_Row": "(.*?) - (.*?)",', repl, line)  
  output.write(updated)
output.close()
input.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

use this regex `(?<=\D|^)(\d{5,}|1[1-9]\d\d|1\d[1-9]\d|1\d\d[1-9]|[2-9]\d{3})(?=\D|$)`

```
(?<=\D|^) symbols before digit
(\d{5,}|1[1-9]\d\d|1\d[1-9]\d|1\d\d[1-9]|[2-9]\d{3}) symbols > 1000
(?=\D|$) symbols after digit
```