# Python: Finding text, transforming it, replacing it

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Can't seem to articulate this problem well enough to look this up. I'm looking to use regular expressions to identify certain strings of text, transform them, and then replace that string with the transformed text.

For instance:
"Some random stock symbol: MSFT AAPL INTC"

If I wanted to replace the stock symbol with say a stock symbol that is linked with HTML, what's the best way to go about doing this?

I can write a regular expression to find the stock symbol and do a simple substitution of a fixed string, but I don't know how to tell Python to "find string in text, transform it, and replace the string with the transformed text"

In this particular example, I could split the string on a space and iterate through the list, but I'd like something that just finds and replaces the text as Python finds it as there might be cases where a consistent delimiter might not be available.

Comment: You can pass a function as replacement parameter to `re.sub`. you can find an example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094975/python-re-sub-question

Comment: You mean something like https://regex101.com/r/qM2nV7/1?

Answer (score 0):

```
    import re

    string = 'Some random stock symbol: MSFT AAPL INTC'
    tickers = re.findall('[A-Z]{4}', string)

    for x in tickers:
       string = re.sub(x, 'example.com/'+x, string)
```

This returns 'Some random stock symbol: example.com/MSFT example.com/AAPL example.com/INTC'

Comment: Thanks. My example should have been better to show more transformation being done on the data instead of simpler things like more static concatenation. The data munging part of the re.sub  in Casimir's comment was more what I was looking for in terms of passing the data to a function, doing something to it, and returning the value. Didn't see it in the Python regexp how-to but it is in the documentation for re.