# Distributing a Python script

Tags: python, cgi

I've recently asked a question about a Python script that can "process" a text string and add a predefined [url] tag (BBCode) to all occurrences of predefined keywords (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28921271/replace-text-in-html-and-bbcode-sample)).

The script is now almost working.

**I have some collaborators who don't necessarily have a Python distribution installed on their computer, is there a way for me to "simply" let them use the script without them installing Python?**

If this is of any help, the script is rather simple, as it does not import any package that is not in Python 2.7 "core" packages (including `BeautifulSoup` for HTML parsing and `urllib2`).

Remark: I've thought of server-side scripting through CGI, but this requires a website which I don't own right now.

Thank you all for your time!

**Solved: `PythonAnywhere` is working for a light-weight, browser-based console, also `py2exe` works really great even though it is more platform-dependent. Thank you all for your input!**

Comment: To run a python script, python must be installed on the computer. There are some tools like [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/) that can help you export it to other formats.

Comment: How about using ssh to connect to a  remote machine where the code is executable? Probably not the best method but it could workout ..

Comment: Hi Brobin and jrsm, first of all thank you for your fast answers! For the ssh method, it could work, I'll consider it if I don't find a "simpler" way because it forces them to install cygwin or Putty I guess. For the py2exe one, I'm going to give it a try tomorrow!

Comment: You can use portable Python. Putty does not need to be installed. It can be copied. Also you can try the provider of the interactive shell at https://www.python.org/

Comment: Hi all, alright so I've been using `PythonAnywhere` which seems to work as intended! Also, `py2exe` did a good job and I've finally opted for this method to share my code. I don't have any feedbacks yet but I think it works. Thank you so much for all your input! Cheers