# Is there a Python equivalent to the Perl /e modifier for regular expressions?

Tags: python, regex

In Perl I can do replacement with regular expressions like this:

```
$text =~ s/([some][pattern])/text_replace($1)/e;

sub text_select {
  my $text = $_[0];
  return "modified_$text";
}
```

Note the /e modifier - it allows to execute any Perl code in "replace to" part of the s/// operator.

How to do the same in Python?

Comment: You can pass a callback function as well in the `re.sub` and do what ever you please with the match object inside. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094975/python-re-sub-question

Comment: Do you mean the substitution of regex matches with the returned value of a function?