# what is the best regular expression to replace non numeric character in a string preceded by certain phrase in python?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have to parse lists of names, addresses, etc. that were OCRed and have invalid/incorrect characters in them and on the state postal code I need to recognize the pattern with a 2 character state followed by a 5 digit postal code and replace any non numeric characters in the postal code. I might have  `OK 7-41.03` at the end of a string I need to remove the hyphen and period. I know that `re.sub('[^0-9]+', '', '7-41.03')` will remove the desired characters but I need it only replace characters in numbers when found at the end of the string and only if preceded by a two character state wrapped in spaces like `OK`. It seems if I add anything to the regular expression as far as a lookbehind expression then I can't seem to get the characters replaced. I've come up with the following but I think there must be a simpler expression to accomplish this. Example:

```
>>> s = 'AT&T RESOURCES, LEC\n15 EAST STH STREET, SUITE 2200\nTULSA, OK 7-41.03'  
>>> s[:re.search('(?<= [A-Z]{2} )[0-9\.-]+$', s).start()] + \  
...     re.sub('[^0-9]+', '', s[re.search('(?<= [A-Z]{2} )[0-9\.-]+$', s).start():])  
'AT&T RESOURCES, LEC\n15 EAST STH STREET, SUITE 2200\nTULSA, OK 74103'
```

This works, but looking for a better simpler way. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make use of `re.sub` callbacks:

```
# Our text
s = 'AT&T RESOURCES, LEC\n15 EAST STH STREET, SUITE 2200\nTULSA, OK 7-41.03'

# A function to be called upon
def repl(m):
    # Remove any non-digit chars
    return re.sub('\D+', '', m.group(0))

# Find 2 capital letters and capture the assumed zip code after it
# Pass the matches to repl
print re.sub('(?<= [A-Z][A-Z] )\S+', repl, s)
```

I'm no Python developer but hopefully the above code works based on what I found at https://stackoverflow.com/a/2095012/2191572

Comment: ah yes, completely forgot about using a function there, hadn't done that in a long time. The `re.sub` needed to be changed to `re.sub('(?<= [A-Z]{2} )\S+', repl, s)`, needed space before and after the state initials, but got me there.

Comment: @observer7 Unfortunately you only provided a very small sample of data so I chose `\b`. I'm sure the OCR scanner produces other inconsistencies which could make the regex fail but at least this is a start =)

Comment: just to be clear, for posterity, in this case, it didn't match the small sample that I provided.  

`>>> re.search('(?<=\b[A-Z][A-Z]\b)\S+', s) is None
True
>>> re.search('(?<= [A-Z][A-Z] )\S+', s) is None
False` Thanks again

Comment: @observer7 That's because you omitted the space after the second `\b` for some reason. Check the edit history because I certainly didn't write `(?<=\b[A-Z][A-Z]\b )\S+` for my own health.